# VNC Connecting issue in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4

Tags: opensuse, suse

I have created one the following instance on AWS (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP4 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0c55353c85ac52c96
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 Service Pack 3 (HVM), EBS General Purpose (SSD) Volume Type. Public Cloud, Advanced Systems Management, Web and Scripting, and Legacy modules enabled) I have installed XRDP & Gnome Desktop Envoirnment.
Also I have set the status as Active & Enable for XRDP in system system services. I have executed the below commands but still the not able to login into the system

**Updated the SUSE installed Gnone & XRDP**

```
zypper update ( to update SUSE Linux Ent. Server)
zypper install -t pattern gnome-basic
zypper install xrdp
```

**Enable VNC Remote Login**

> Open yast, Select "Network Services",
>     Select first entry "Remote > Administration with VNC" Enable service

**Configure Window Manager to use Gnome**

> Edit file /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager Change entry DEFAULT_WM="" to
>   DEFAULT_WM="gnome"

**Startup the RDP service and make it start automatically after Reboot**

```
service xrdp start
chkconfig --set xrdp on
systemctl start xrdp
systemctl enable xrdp
```

But I am getting the below error : Let me know your thoughts so that I can fix this issue.

> please wait, we now perform access control... Reply rom access
>   control: Success Connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 sesman
>   connect ok sending login info to session manager, please wait...
>   xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successfull for display 200
>
> VNC started connecting Waiting 2000 ms for VNC to start... VNC
>   connecting to 127.0.0.1 6100 VNC error - problem connecting

[image]